# More than 255 event parameters with indicators in the DEM

Tags: autosar

I am running into a limitation of the DEM configuration when I want to configure more than 255 DemEventParameters (DTCs). Each of these DemEventParameters needs to trigger an indicator (RedStopLamp or AmberWarningLamp) to inform the driver via SAE J1939 DM1 that one or more events are active.

Because every DemEventParameter has it's own DemEventClass which has it's own DemIndicatorAttribute. Each DemIndicatorAttribute is referenced with a DemIndicatorRef to one of the two DemIndicators. But the limitation is that the DemIndicatorAttribute has a upper multiplicity of 255. So with this approach you can have a maximum of 255 events which triggers one of the indicators.

In theory only two DemIndicatorAttributes would be enough since there are only two lamps to set in a DM1 message but I don't see how this can be handled in the DEM.

The only thing I can think of is to have non DemIndicatorAttributes to the existing DemEventParameters. Get the status of all these events cyclically and and if one error or warning is found set 1 or 2 events which has an attribute to the RedStopLamp and AmberWarmingLamp. But this would need to be done by a separate SWC which needs to be maintained next to the DEM configurations.

I hope there is a better way?

[image]

Comment: I actually read that as: Each DemEventParameter can have up to 255 DemIndicatorAttribute container. The DemIndicatorAttribute contains a reference by DemIndicatorRef to a DemIndicator. So, you could have 2 DemEvents conifgured each in a DemEventParameter, each having a single DemIndicatorAttribute with id 0, referencing the same DemIndicator.

Comment: That is indeed what I also read: "Each DemEventParameter can have up to 255 DemIndicatorAttribute". 
And this is what I indeed currently do: "So, you could have 2 DemEvents conifgured each in a DemEventParameter, each having a single DemIndicatorAttribute with id 0, referencing the same DemIndicator." But if you want to do this more than 255 times this doesn't work anymore. So apparently we should not read this as "each DemEventParameter" but read it as: "In totoal not more than 255." Or at least that is what the implementer of the AUTOSAR stack read.

Comment: I solved this first issue by creating two dummy events (one for each of the two indicators I am using) The other events will trigger a function which holds a counter which will set these dummy events. 
But the next issue is that for each event the DemMaxNumberEventEntryPrimary needs to be increased but this parameter has a limit of 255 so the data type of this parameter is a uint8 which still limits the number of events to 255. See requirement ECUC_Dem_00690 of the DEM specification.